# How to change this javascript Code for JSOUP library in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, web-scraping, jsoup

I have written and tested this code in console Window of chrome and it is giving me the desired result. But I want this same code for JSOUP in android. Please tell me how to do it. I tried to do some modification and change it to be used in android, but I did not succeed.

This is the javascript code

```
document.querySelector('ul').getElementsByTagName('img')[2].getAttribute('alt')
```

And this was my modified code which did not worked.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
doc.select("ul").tagName("img").get(2).getElementsByAttribute("alt").text();
```

Comment: Please add more relative information. What exactly means that code did not work, what did it return? was there an error? If so add the error log

Comment: Actually i am trying to get the alt text of img which is under 'ul' tag. The javascript code was returning the alt text of img when i tried to run it in console window of chrome. But when i tried to implement it in android, it was returning a null.(I was trying to extract the text and show it in toast message. So as it was returning null, i was getting error "Please Set A text or view") I guess, there is some error in my code for JSOUP. So thats what i am trying to figure it out. Hope you understood.

Comment: Please provide a sample HTML or an URL and the desired output of your jsoup query.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the whole element by attribute instead of taking the attribute of an element. Proper way to take alt text would be

```
doc.select("ul").tagName("img").get(2).attr("alt");
```

Comment: I tried the exact code earlier also but it is giving me this error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0